# iPhone - Preventing UIImageView to rotate when switching from vertical to horizontal

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, camera, rotation

I have an app with a camera overlay.
Into this overlay view I have 2 imageViews and 1 View.
1 image view for overlay graphic drawing.
I image view to put the taken picture into it.
I custom View for some custom drawing.

When the  iPhone is in horizontal position when taking the photo, the displayed photo into the image view is rotated. So I have a big space on both sides of the picture.

I've tried to put this into the OverlayViewController but without any effect :

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

All view and image view have the same params into IB (for those params that are common).

How may I prevent the picture to rotate into the image view when the phone is not vertical ?

Note : I must be able to keep the ability to auto rotate the other views that I can display in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller's `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method, you can apply an opposite rotation to the UIImageView's `transform` property. For example, if the controller is rotating to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, that is a 90° clockwise rotation from portrait. So if you apply a 90° counterclockwise rotation to the image view, it will seem to not have rotated at all.

Comment: could you give me an example of the kind of code you're thinking about ? I have fought with the transform property for hours to mirror back the front camera picture, and I'd like not to be lost once again  :-)

Comment: @Oliver: `imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);` Or `-M_PI_2`, I can never remember which is which.

Comment: I'v etested your solution, none of both does the job :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the window directly, which won't auto-rotate.

Comment: which window are you talking about ? I'm into an overlay view on a camera picker view.